# Worklight 6.1 - error on sending notification to android device on real server

Tags: android, notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm trying to send notification to android device.
On my Worklight Studio I have succeeded to make subscription + notification.

When I trying to do it on real worklight server(on liberty), *I have succeeded to make subscription*, but I can't send notification.

I'm trying to send notification on browser like that:

```
http://serverIp:9080/worklighttime/dev/invoke?adapter=PushAdapter&procedure=submitNotification&parameters=[%27user%27,%27text message%27]
```

At the adapter I added:

```
<procedure name="submitNotification" securityTest="wl_unprotected" />
```

And, still I get this error:

```
 Exception thrown by application class 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter:235'
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Can not access development servlets in production mode
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:235)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Can not access development servlets in production mode
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:136)
... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this part from the error message:

> Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Can not access development
>   servlets in production mode at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:136)

Now see the URL you are using:

```
http://serverIp:9080/worklighttime/dev/invoke?adapter=PushAdapter&procedure=submitNotification&parameters=[%27user%27,%27text
message%27]
```

The `/dev/` denotes basically a "development servlet", which as the error says - cannot be used when in production. "In production" basically means "any server that is not inside Worklight Studio", Worklight Studio being the development environment.

Try to remove the `/dev/` from the URL and see whether this helps, or maybe a different error will then be given.