# Worklight 6.0.0.2 javax.servlet.ServletException: Can not access development servlets in production mode

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Sometime I see in my websphere proile log for Worklight have an error message:

```
[Servlet Error]-[DevRootServlet]: javax.servlet.ServletException: Can not access development servlets in production mode
```

I don't know where is error message come from? but my WL application still working fine.
Anybody can help me to fix this issue?
I'm using WL version 6.0.0.2

Thanks

Comment: Are you invoking adapters with /dev in the URL path? provide the full exception log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if my answer from another similar question helps you: [Worklight 6.1 - error on sending notification to android device on real server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911492/worklight-6-1-error-on-sending-notification-to-android-device-on-real-server)

---

Take a look at this part from the error message:

> Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Can not access development
>   servlets in production mode at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:136)

Now see the URL you are using:

```
http://serverIp:9080/worklighttime/dev/invoke?adapter=PushAdapter&procedure=submitNotification&parameters=[%27user%27,%27text
message%27]
```

The `/dev/` denotes basically a "development servlet", which as the error says - cannot be used when in production. "In production" basically means "any server that is not inside Worklight Studio", Worklight Studio being the development environment.

Try to remove the `/dev/` from the URL and see whether this helps, or maybe a different error will then be given.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the environment (production) when calling an adapter procedure using http://{Host}:{Port}/{Context}/apps/services/api/{AppName}/{environment}/query (source: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_do_worklight_server_performance_testing?lang=en)?